# jenkins build job on PR accepted

Tags: git, github, jenkins

I want to trigger a Jenkins build job on a particular action i.e. PR accepted. I tried using Jenkins Poll SCM without giving any schedule, but that gets trigger on when the PR is raised.

How can I make sure that the build is only triggered when PR is merged/accepted.

Also I am using github.

Comment: You should probably provide (sanitized) screenshots of the plugin configuration and relevant part of job configuration. Also relevant snippet of the the build console log *text*, if there's anything which looks like relevant, might be helpful.

Comment: You could use a GitHub webhook to trigger a build, however there is no webhook action for "PR merged", so you would only be able to watch for new commits to `master` (or whichever branch you're merging to).

Answer (score 0):

[GitHub pull request builder plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+pull+request+builder+plugin)

you can trigger your job by using trigger phrase which you add as a comment in your PR.[image]

Comment: GHPRB ignores all comments (trigger phrases) on a PR after it is merged or closed. This won't work.